# How much broadcast time did it take for Planet Namek to blow up?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In *Dragon Ball Z*, during Goku's fight with Frieza, Frieza decides to destroy the planet Namek. However he fails to do so, but he claims that the planet will blow up in 5 minutes, at the most, but several episodes later, the two are still seen fighting.

Exactly how much broadcast time (real time) elapsed before the planet actually blew up?

I am looking for the total **broadcast time** (NOT the time passed in-universe) it took for planet Namek to explode.

**Excluding**:

- OP and ED theme time
- Commercials
- Events happening concurrently with the Frieza battle

But **including**:

- Fillers (the concurrent event rule applies here as well)

**Starting** from:

- When Frieza says that it will take five minutes

**Ending** when:

- The planet actually blows up

Comment: I haven't seen the scene, but I know that sometimes simultaneous scenes are shown (i.e. fighting in place A will be shown and then talking that happened at the same time will be shown). Do you want all the simultaneous scenes included separately?

Comment: 5 Namekian minutes could be a way more then 5 earth minutes.

Comment: If it would help someone find the answer, [this video on youtube](http://youtu.be/1Uq1hr3BkeE?t=2h38m50s) which merges multiple episodes of Dragon Ball Z in order to get the full fight between Goku and Frieza into a single video has the 5 minute counter start at 2:38:50. The total time for the video is 4:13:45. So the total elapsed time to that point where Frieza is dead is 1 hour 24 minutes and 55 seconds. However, this is not the actual destruction of Namek.

Comment: The fights are actually happening a lot faster than they appear to be, and also, [Talking is a free action](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TalkingIsAFreeAction)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the [TVTropes link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TalkingIsAFreeAction) I linked in the comments had the answer

> Taken to insanity during Goku's fight with Freeza. Freeza destroys the
>   core and gives the planet five minutes until implosion. Ten episodes
>   (approximately three hours of screentime for each of the scenes that
>   are playing out simultaneously) and over three hundred lines of dialog
>   for the two fighters later the planet finally collapses.

So there you go.

- 10 episodes
- 3 hours (roughly)
- 100 lines of dialog

although, apparently it was

> Lampshaded snarkily in the dub. With ten episodes to go, Frieza has a
>   line to the effect that the planet is "a tough one... it'll probably
>   last another two minutes."

Comment: +1 for actually finding an article that cites the approximate time. Far larger than most estimates though.

Comment: I checked the episode lists and the events should happen between episode 97 to 107, a 10 episode span. So the 3 hour approximation seems reasonable given 20 minutes per episode. The counter should begin towards the end of episode 97 and end around the beginning of episode 107, but I don't have access to the episodes to confirm this.

Comment: it was the longest 5 minutes in all of the history

Comment: +1 Other then the fact that the quote you posted says **three** hundred lines of dialog though, instead of just 100...